# Extract text within quotation marks on webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping

Is there a simple way to extract all text on a webpage that is within quotation marks? Simply parsing the HTML code as string doesn't do the trick it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the yahoo link with any link you want. This will return a list of all sentences and words between double quotes.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Comment
import urllib
import re


def tag_visible(element):
    if element.parent.name in ['style', 'script', 'head', 'title', 'meta', '[document]']:
        return False
    if isinstance(element, Comment):
        return False
    return True


def text_from_html(body):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(body, 'html.parser')
    texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
    visible_texts = filter(tag_visible, texts)  
    return u" ".join(t.strip() for t in visible_texts)

html = urllib.urlopen('https://news.yahoo.com/poll-biden-leads-trump-four-165851808.html').read()

alltext = text_from_html(html)
charmap = { 0x201c : u'"',
            0x201d : u'"',
            0x2018 : u"'",
            0x2019 : u"'" }

alltext = alltext.translate(charmap)

final = re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"', alltext)
```